# Application for both mobile and pad

Tags: android, xml, layout, xamarin.android

I'm creating an application, mostly the UI design of it. However it's crucial that the layout looks ok on both android phones and pads, how do i achieve this? Do i need to use different layout versions?

Since the different devices got different resolution and display sizes i can't use absolute positioning. What are the common ways of designing layout for different devices? Any tips?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/ read this before starting programming for android(whole guide) ... then you will find two topics about this ... "Supporting Multiple Screens" and new one "Supporting Tablets and Handsets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using Fragments in you UI.

[Fragments 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

[Fragments 2](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

The above links might help you.

I hope this helps...